# Merging Pull requests from a sub-branch, particularly on Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

Suppose the following happens in an Azure DevOps, GIT environment

1. Developer 1 creates "Branch A" from "master" to work on a bug.
2. Developer 2 creates "Branch B", *from* "Branch A" to do some
   extra work for Developer 1
3. When the Developer 2 is done, he pushes his changes to B and creates a pull request for the Developer 1
4. Developer 1 uses the Azure DevOps web interface, approves, then completes completes the pull request

Now typically, when we just have a simple branch off master, everything gets merged to master and that's great.  But in this case, with a sub-branch off a branch, I want to be sure of something:

When the Branch B gets merged in my scenario, it is *only merged back to the immediate parent "Branch A"*, right?  In other words, Azure DevOps doesn't merge anything all the way to "master", does it?

This might be a dumb question but discussions of pull requests (that I have seen) tend to talk about a simple, branch-off-master scenario.  Besides, I'm  not sure if Azure DevOps, in the interest of making things easier, might use any defaults that would not be assumed in another Git environment so I feel I should ask this to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Pull Request is merging one branch into another branch of your choosing.**

In #3, when Developer2 creates a Pull Request (PR), he must choose a source and target branch, and the answer to your question is whichever target branch he chooses.

Therefore either option is possible. If he creates the PR for `Branch-B` into `master`, then that's where it will be merged, and in that case, assuming Developer1 agrees with it, `Branch-A` can simply be deleted since it will already be merged into `master` when `Branch-B` was merged in.

If instead he creates a PR from `Branch-B` to `Branch-A`, then the result will be that `Branch-A` now contains the new changes as well, and then `Branch-A` can be PR'd into `master` when Developer1 is ready. Note that if this is the desired goal, you probably don't even need to use a PR. Typically `master` would be protected and require a PR, but `Branch-A` would not, so instead of making a new branch off of `Branch-A`, Developer2 could notify Developer1 that they are going to add some commits to `Branch-A`, and then they can do so and push out `Branch-A`. Developer1 would then pull `Branch-A` to get the latest and create the PR into `master` when ready.